# Is it possible to UNNEST an array created using ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT
  `order`.source AS order_source,
  `order`.key AS order_key,
  ANY_VALUE(`order`.date) AS order_date,
  order_product.key AS key,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.sku) AS sku,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.name) AS name,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.quantity) AS quantity,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.subtotal) AS revenue,
  ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(moved_quants) AS moved_quants
 FROM 
  `analytics.spr.stock_move_shipments`
 GROUP BY
  `order`.source,
  `order`.key,
  order_product.key
```

Each row in `analytics.spr.stock_move_shipments` has repeated `moved_quants` field. As you can see in the query, I am grouping rows together and creating an array of moved_quants for the group using `ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG`.

However, what I would really like to do is perform some aggregation on those `moved_quants` and display those results in each row. I thought I could just change the last line of the `SELECT` statement to something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  `order`.source AS order_source,
  `order`.key AS order_key,
  ANY_VALUE(`order`.date) AS order_date,
  order_product.key AS key,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.sku) AS sku,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.name) AS name,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.quantity) AS quantity,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.subtotal) AS revenue,
  (SELECT SUM(t1.inventory_value) FROM UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(moved_quants)) t1) AS inventory_value
 FROM 
  `analytics.spr.stock_move_shipments`
 GROUP BY
  `order`.source,
  `order`.key,
  order_product.key
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
Aggregate function ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG not allowed in UNNEST
```

Why is this not allowed? Shouldn't I be able to simply `UNNEST` the array created by `ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG`? Is there some better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the simplest option for you - just to transform lightly what you already have to work as you want and avoid UNNESTing just aggregated array in same query - so you just separate it

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(moved_quants), 
  (SELECT SUM(inventory_value) FROM UNNEST(moved_quants)) AS inventory_value
FROM (
SELECT
  `order`.source AS order_source,
  `order`.key AS order_key,
  ANY_VALUE(`order`.date) AS order_date,
  order_product.key AS key,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.sku) AS sku,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.name) AS name,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.quantity) AS quantity,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.subtotal) AS revenue,
  ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(moved_quants) AS moved_quants
 FROM 
  `analytics.spr.stock_move_shipments`
 GROUP BY
  `order`.source,
  `order`.key,
  order_product.key
)
```

note: typed on fly and not tested ...

But even simpler solution is below

```
SELECT
  `order`.source AS order_source,
  `order`.key AS order_key,
  ANY_VALUE(`order`.date) AS order_date,
  order_product.key AS key,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.sku) AS sku,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.name) AS name,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.quantity) AS quantity,
  ANY_VALUE(order_product.subtotal) AS revenue,
  SUM((SELECT SUM(inventory_value) FROM UNNEST(moved_quants))) AS inventory_value
 FROM 
  `analytics.spr.stock_move_shipments`
 GROUP BY
  `order`.source,
  `order`.key,
  order_product.key
```

I would definitely went with this last one!

Comment: Thanks! Last one is great, but what would you do if you actually needed multiple values from the quants? I was just using one for simplicity, but really I need to `SUM(inventory_value)`, `SUM(tariff_amount)`, and some other fields from within the array. The best I could do was your first solution but using `SELECT AS STRUCT` to get all the fields I want. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: yes, in this case you can use first solution with `AS STRUCT` ! I think this would be the most optimal approach in case of multiple SUMs, while second one - good for just one SUM

Comment: I'm not sure the second solution works. I'm getting `Each function argument is an expression, not a query; to use a query as an expression, the query must be wrapped with additional parentheses to make it a scalar subquery expression`

Comment: i just tested second one with simplified data and it works for me! in any case you ahve first one  - right! as of second  - just add extra `()` as in `SUM((SELECT SUM(inventory_value) FROM UNNEST(moved_quants))) AS inventory_value`

Comment: as I said  - i was free-typing - so looks like i just missed those extra brackets  - when i did the quick test that I mentioned above  - I actually had those extras in - that is why it worked  - so I just updated answer :o) thank  you for checking!

Comment: Great! Glad we did it!